# Kony - ant build error

Tags: android, google-maps, ant, temenos-quantum

After add maps android api, i have this error in build:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[exec-shell]        [dx] java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\rodrigo.dagnese\KonySampleApps\temp\Map\build\luaandroid\dist\Map\LibProjects\google-play-services_lib\bin\classes.jar (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado)
[exec-shell]        [dx]    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
[exec-shell]        [dx]    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
[exec-shell]        [dx]    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
[exec-shell]        [dx]    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
[exec-shell]        [dx]    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
[exec-shell]        [dx]    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
[exec-shell]        [dx]    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
[exec-shell]        [dx]    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
[exec-shell]        [dx]    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
[exec-shell]        [dx]    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
[exec-shell]        [dx]    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
[exec-shell]        [dx]    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
[exec-shell]        [dx]    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
[exec-shell]        [dx] 1 error; aborting
[exec-shell] 
[exec-shell] BUILD FAILED
[exec-shell] C:\Users\rodrigo.dagnese\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:888: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec-shell] C:\Users\rodrigo.dagnese\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:890: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec-shell] C:\Users\rodrigo.dagnese\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:902: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec-shell] C:\Users\rodrigo.dagnese\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:283: null returned: 1
[exec-shell] 
[exec-shell] Total time: 16 seconds
[11-19-2015 03:22:49]Ant build error=exec-shell returned: 1
[11-19-2015 03:22:49]Build Generation failed for platform Android.
```

Someone know what means that classes.jar and how I can fix it?

Comment: Have you already `Clean & Build` the app?

Answer (score 1):

Check your environment variables. You need Java JDK (7.79 worked for me) installed in root.

```
Path:
[..]
C:\Android\platform-tools;
C:\Android\tools;
C:\Kony\Ant\bin;
C:\Kony\ImageMagick;
C:\Android\platform-tools;
C:\Android\tools;
C:\Java\bin;
C:\Java\jre;

JAVA_HOME:
C:\Java

JRE_HOME:
C:\Java\jre
```